# Proving that cubing (modulo certain numbers) is injective

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $p$ be a prime and let $S= \{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$. Define the function $f(x)$ with domain and co-domain $S$, such that, $f$ maps $x$ to the residue of $x^3 \pmod p$. Show that if p $\not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $f$ is an injective function.

I have tried solve this question by assuming that there are two different $x$ that map to the same residue and then looking for a contradiction, so that I get $x_1=x_2$. But I can't seem to get there. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please keep answers to the level of introductory number theory.

Comment: Since you are working with invertible residues, $x_1^3 \equiv x_2^3$ is equivalent to $(x_1/x_2)^3 \equiv 1$.  What do you know about orders of elements?

Comment: I know what the order of an element is (the element being co-prime to the modulus). I know Fermat's little theorem, the euler-Fermat theorem. I know that the order of an element must be a divisor of p-1, I know that: a^n≡a^m(mod p) iff n≡m(mod(order of a mod p)).

Comment: Sooooo, if $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $a^3 \equiv 1 \pmod p$, what can you conclude about the order of $a$ mod $p$?

Comment: Since p is prime, by Fermat's theorem, 3 divides (p-1) and so there is a contradiction and the proof is complete. Am I right?

Comment: You skipped an important detail: just because $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod p$ doesn't mean the order of $a$ is exactly $k$ (why?).  You need to give some justification before you claim that the order of $a$ is $3$, since it's not immediate from $a^3 \equiv 1$.

Comment: Ok, I have shown that the order cannot be 1, but how do I show that It can't be 2, or is this the wrong approach?

Comment: Oh, I think I have it, if 2 is the order, this implies that 2 divides 3, since a^3≡1(mod p)  so 3 must be the order.